# Expand $f(z) = \frac{z}{(z+1)(z-2)}$ in a Laurent series

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, laurent-series

$f(z) =\frac{z}{(z+1)(z-2)}$

given $1 < |z+1| <3$

So I have to write it as the power of $(z+1)$, but using partial fractions I get 
$-\frac{z}{3(z+1)} + \frac{z}{3(z-2)}$ and I don't know how to deal with this $z$ on the nominator. How can I write it as power of $(z+1)$?

*(it is probably something very simple, but I have no ideia)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One may write, for $1<|z+1|<3$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{z}{z-2}&=\frac{(z-2)+2}{z-2}
\\&=1+\frac{2}{z-2}
\\&=1-\frac23\cdot\frac{1}{1-\dfrac{z+1}3}
\\&=1-\frac23\cdot \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\dfrac{z+1}3\right)^n
\end{align}
$$ finally,
$$
\frac{z}{(z+1)(z-2)}=\frac{1}{3(z+1)}-\frac{2}{9}-\frac23\cdot \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\dfrac{z+1}3\right)^n.
$$

Comment: Oh, now I get it! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Mark You are welcome.